# C++ dictionary API

Tags: c++, api

Does anyone know of a dictionary API for C++ that allows me to search for a word and get back the definition?

(I don't mind if it is an online API and I have to use JSON or XML to parse it)

*Edit:* Sorry, I meant a dictionary as in definitions for words. Not a C++ Map. Sorry for confusion.

Comment: Are you looking for something with a pre-defined list of words, or are you intending to create the list of words/definitions yourself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use aonaware APIs. (http://services.aonaware.com/DictService/DictService.asmx). I dont know the cost though.

Answer (score 23):

Use [`std::map<string,string>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map)
then you can do:

```
#include <map> 
map["apple"] = "A tasty fruit";
map["word"] = "A group of characters that makes sense";
```

and then

```
map<char,int>::iterator it;
cout << "apple => " << mymap.find("apple")->second << endl;
cout << "word => " << mymap.find("word")->second << endl;
```

to print the definitions

Comment: If you know you are inserting, you should use the `insert` function. The brackets should be used for accessing, updating, or inserting when you don't know if the key exists, otherwise you can incur significant overhead. Also, `mymap.find("apple")->second` can be very dangerous if the key doesn't exist.

Answer (score 10):

Try using the `std::map`:

```
#include <map>
map<string, string> dictionary;

// adding
dictionary.insert(make_pair("foo", "bar"));

// searching
map<string, string>::iterator it = dictionary.find("foo");
if(it != dictionary.end())
    cout << "Found! " << it->first << " is " << it->second << "\n";
// prints: Found! Foo is bar
```

Comment: To make use of 'std::make_pair'. "#include <utility>" should be added.

Answer (score 1):

I have just started to learn C++. Since I have experience in Python, and I'm looking for similar data structure as `dictionary` in Python. Here is what I found:

```
#include <stream>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

int main() { 

    map<string,string> dict;
    dict["foo"] = "bar";
    cout<<dict["foo"]<<"\n";

    return 0; 
}
```

compile and run, you will got:

```
bar
```

Comment: I believe OP wants a tool already filled with english words' definitions, not to learn how to use dictionaries in C++.